# In clojure records, how to map array of records to vector?

Tags: clojure

If I have an vector of records that implement a protocol, and want to map the return value of a method of each of those records to another vector, is there a clean way to do that?  I can just use map with an anonymous function wrapping the call to the method, but that seems a bit clunky.

Edited:

Well, actually, there's nothing to this.  You just use the method as the function in first argument to the call to map.

```
(map mymethod myrecords)
```

Due to an unrelated mistake, that wasn't working for me and I thought I had to do...

```
(map #(mymethod %) myrecords)
```

...which is what I thought was clunky.  So the question is invalid.

Comment: why does that seem clunky? it perfectly does concurrent processing of records which is one of clojure's main motives

Comment: How does concurrency come into play here? The `map` function returns a lazy sequence, but does not make any promise regarding parallel processing to yield the elements in that lazy sequence. Were you thinking of `pmap`?

Comment: yes,i understood it the wrong way,yeah pmap.

Comment: @KaKa, it's a bit clunky because the closure literal doesn't do anything in-and-of-itself, it just directly wraps the other function. It doesn't add anything, so it's noise.

Comment: What Arthur says is right. You should move your "edit" into a separate answer for this question instead of including it as part of the question. Answering your own question is a perfectly acceptable practice here.

Answer (score 1):

Methods on records work with map like every other method:

```
(defprotocol Foo 
  (foo [this]))

(defrecord Bar [bar]
   Foo 
   (foo [this] bar)

(map foo [(Bar. 1) (Bar. 2)])
=> (1 2)
```